# CFD work with Python

Tags: python

I am a meteorologist, and lately I am trying to investigate the possibility of building my one sondes.

In order to do that, I have the following work plan :

1. I would like to generate 3D models [pyformex](http://www.nongnu.org/pyformex/). An alternative is [openSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/). But I start with pyformex - to generate simple cylindrical sonde shapes with associated extra features, e.g. intake tube or such.
2. Next, I will like to split it in Meshes, using [PyDistMesh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDistMesh/1.2); as well as prepare a raytraced point cloud model with [Xrt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xrt).
3. In the third step, I would like to perform the CFD works.

Now, my questions :

1. Are there some other simple Python Libraries to generate 3D models? I would like a very simple system, where i can issue commands like `p = Parallelogram (length, height, width)`, or `p.position(x,y,z)` etc. It would be nice to have built in mouse interaction - that is, a built in drawing component, which I can use to display the model, and rotate/ zoom/pan with mouse.
2. Any other mesh generation tools?
3. For this step, I would need a multiphysics system. I tried to use OpenFOAM, it is too huge (to hack through). I have taken a look at [SU2](http://su2.stanford.edu/), but it seems to focus more on aerospace engineering, than Fluid Dynamics (I would like to simulate the flight of the sonde - which is closer to aerospace engineering, as well as the state of the atmosphere). [Fluidity](https://github.com/FluidityProject) seems to suit my needs better, but I dont find a python fork thereof. So are there some general purpose, not too bloated up, multiphysics python library for geophysical and general hydrodynamic simulations? I have taken a look a MOOSE, also dont find a python binding for it.
4. Scientific visualization : Are there some 3 or 4 (or may be higher dimensional) visualization libraries? I would prefer to issue simple commands as `Plot` instead of first generating a window / form, and then putting the graphs on it, if possible.

FINALLY, and most importantly, if the same can be done by C++ or Fortan, or some other language besides java, I would also consider using those.

Comment: Have you considered breaking this down and reducing the scope of this question? If you do that then you'll see that a lot of these answers are already posted on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://freecadweb.org/. This seems to be under active development. It is a fairly complete open source CAD package written in python. I believe it also has tools for meshing.

For cfd, you might want to consider openfoam - http://www.openfoam.com/. This is an open source cfd package with the obligatory steep learning curve. There seem to be some python libraries to be available that link to it, however I'm not sure how active these are:

- http://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Contrib/PyFoam
- http://pythonflu.wikidot.com/